# Async function to scrape subreddits using Cheerio returns undefined

Tags: node.js, express, web-scraping, cheerio

The script by itself works great (entering the url manually, writing a json file using the fs module, node script_name.js) but within a Express get request it returns undefined.

So I've built a simple frontend to let the user enter the subreddit name to be scraped.
And here's where the problem is:

##### Express controller

```js
const run = require("../run");
requestPosts: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { subreddit } = req.body;
      const response = await run(subreddit);
      //console.log(response);
      res.json(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },
```

##### Cheerio functions

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const { load } = require("cheerio");
let posts = [];

async function getImage(postLink) {
  const { data } = await axios(postLink);
  const $ = load(data);
  return $("a.post-link").attr("href");
}

async function run(url) {
  try {
    console.log(url);
    const { data } = await axios(url);
    const $ = load(data);
    $(".thing.linkflair.link").map(async (i, e) => {
      const title = $(e)
        .find(".entry.unvoted .top-matter .title .title")
        .text();
      const user = $(e)
        .find(".entry.unvoted .top-matter .tagline .author")
        .text();
      const profileLink = `https://old.reddit.com/user/${user}`;
      const postLink = `https://old.reddit.com/${$(e).find("a").attr("href")}`;
      // const thumbail = $(e).find("a img").attr("src");
      const image = await getImage(postLink);
      posts.push({
        id: i + 1,
        title,
        postLink,
        image,
        user: { user, profileLink },
      });
    });
    const nextPage = $(".next-button a").attr("href");
    if (nextPage) {
      await run(nextPage);
    } else {
      return posts;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

module.exports = run;
```

I've tried working with Promise((resolve, reject) => {}).
I think it's returning undefined because maybe the code its not synchronized.

(idk if it makes sense, i've just started programming)

Answer (score 0):

`.map()` is not promise-aware and does not wait for your promises to finish.  So, `$(".thing.linkflair.link").map()` finishes long before any of the asynchronous functions inside its callback do.  Thus you try to return `posts` BEFORE it has been populated.

Passing an `async` callback to `.map()` will return an array of promises.  You can use `Promise.all()` on those promises to know when they are done and once you're doing that, you may as well just return each `post` object rather that using a higher level scoped/shared object, thus making the code more self contained.

I would suggest this code:

```
async function run(url) {
    try {
        console.log(url);
        const { data } = await axios(url);
        const $ = load(data);
        const posts = await Promise.all($(".thing.linkflair.link").map(async (i, e) => {
            const title = $(e)
                .find(".entry.unvoted .top-matter .title .title")
                .text();
            const user = $(e)
                .find(".entry.unvoted .top-matter .tagline .author")
                .text();
            const profileLink = `https://old.reddit.com/user/${user}`;
            const postLink = `https://old.reddit.com/${$(e).find("a").attr("href")}`;
            // const thumbail = $(e).find("a img").attr("src");
            const image = await getImage(postLink);
            // return a post object
            return {
                id: i + 1,
                title,
                postLink,
                image,
                user: { user, profileLink },
            };
        }));
        const nextPage = $(".next-button a").attr("href");
        if (nextPage) {
            const newPosts = await run(nextPage);
            // add these posts to the ones we already have
            posts.push(...newPosts);
        }
        return posts;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```